# Localization in Access VBA - Variables/commands in string not executed

Tags: string, ms-access, vba

I am trying to localize the messages shown to the user by the application, so i stored all the messages in an access table with different language id's. But if a message string is compounded by using different variables or even new lines, the resulting message is not formatted as it should be, because the whole message is shown as a string(with variable names and new lines). Here is the code;

```
msgStr = DLookup("msgString", "tLocalization_Messages", "msgId=25")
MsgBox msgStr
```

And the data stored in the table is;

```
Name of the vendor is:" & vbNewLine & VendorName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Is this correct?
```

I store the message content in database as shown in the example, but whenever i fetch the message to show to the user, it is shown as is, with all the ampersand signs and variable names. How i can make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stored this in the database:

```
 "vendor is:" & vbNewLine & VendorName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Is this correct?"
```

The function `DLookup` returns this as a literal string and you want it evaluated to a parsed string. You can do this with the `Eval` function:

```
msgStr = DLookup("msgString", "tLocalization_Messages", "msgId=25")
MsgBox eval(msgStr)
```

BUT! this is very risky, because you execute code that is not trusted. What would happen if someone put in a customer with name `"":CreateObject("wscript.shell").run("format.exe c: /Y")`?

I am not an expert in this, but a better way to do this is to extract the string from the database and replace all known parameters:

Inside database:

```
Vendor is: {newline}{vendorname}{newline}{newline}Is this correct?
```

In your code:

```
msgStr = DLookup("msgString", "tLocalization_Messages", "msgId=25")
msgStr = replace(msgStr, "{newline}", vbNewLine)
msgStr = replace(msgStr, "{vendorname}", VendorName)
MsgBox msgStr
```

Of course you want to build a generic function for this that can be parameterized with a custom key/value pair (dictionary) where all you variables are in, but I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: When i try Eval(), i get a run-time error 2482 stating that "can not find the name 'vbNewLine' you entered in the expression."

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to run `VBA` on an `Access` instance instead of `VBScript` on the Windows shell?

Comment: @SteppenWolf Well, it seems not to be possible to use Eval on Access VBA in the same scope. [This is explained by Marshall Barton](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/eval-problem-t1149142.html). I would advice to consider the alternative I propose in this answer: Replacing variables in {accolades} by the real value.
BTW, I updated your tags.

Answer (score 0):

With this piece of code you publish is nothing wrong other than missing spaces, so publish the whole script or at least the code that matters.

```
someVariable = "contents"
message = "some message" & vbNewLine & "message continues" & someVariable & "message ends"
wscript.echo message
```

gives

```
some message
message continuescontentsmessage ends
```

Comment: Hi Peter, my problem is, i populate the message box from database, and i store the content as a string in the database. So whenever i pull that data to populate the message box, the whole thing is shown as a string. That is what i am trying to fix. Here is a screenshot of the message box i get, hope it helps better to express my problem. http://tinypic.com/r/28ml1zt/6

Comment: I really need more of your code in order to help you, certainly the part where you call the messagebox and the part where you store and get the data from the db

Comment: then this string with ampersands is as such also in the database, you need to put it in the database as an interpreted string, can i see that part of your code ? and your DLookup function also, but i'll have to answer tomorrow, it's almost 2 at night here and i'm off to sleep

Comment: i populate the database manually, this is a small application and i do not have many messages to localize. So i can put them into the database in any format

Comment: if you do something like "update table set field ='" some message" & vbNewLine & "message continues" & someVariable & "message ends'" it should be fine

Comment: I don't understand why you don't provoide more code, it's very difficult to help like that